# Iterate through a complexed query, performing comparisons and logics using typescript/javascript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, ebnf

I have a project and it is including reading a zip file from the disk, unzip data and read all the files inside then build a `JSON` file out of all given zipped data. Then we are supposed to get a query and by applying the query to the `JSON` files extract data and print them on the screen. my problem is iterating over the query in a way that I could fulfill all the logic and conditions. This is an example of a simple query.

```
 {
   "WHERE":{
      "GT":{
     "courses_avg":97
  }
 },
"OPTIONS":{
  "COLUMNS":[
     "courses_dept",
     "courses_avg"
  ],
  "ORDER":"courses_avg",
      "FORM":"TABLE"
   }
}
```

However, we are asked to handle complicated queries.
this is the EBNF file which defines the query

```
QUERY ::='{'BODY ', ' OPTIONS '}'

BODY ::= 'WHERE:{'  FILTER '}'
OPTIONS ::= 'OPTIONS:{' COLUMNS ', ' ('ORDER:' key ', ')? VIEW '}'

FILTER ::= (LOGICCOMPARISON | MCOMPARISON | SCOMPARISON | NEGATION)

LOGICCOMPARISON ::= LOGIC ':[{' FILTER ('}, {' FILTER )* '}]'  
MCOMPARISON ::= MCOMPARATOR ':{' key ':' number '}'  
SCOMPARISON ::= 'IS:{' key ':' [*]? string [*]? '}'  
NEGATION ::= 'NOT :{' FILTER '}'

LOGIC ::= 'AND' | 'OR' 
MCOMPARATOR ::= 'LT' | 'GT' | 'EQ' 

COLUMNS ::= 'COLUMNS:[' (key ',')* key ']' 
VIEW ::= 'FORM : TABLE'  

key ::= string '_' string
```

My Question is how to handle a complicated query? how should I iterate through and perform specific functions and get the result?

My TA told me to look at the query like a tree that AND and OR have only two nodes and you need to handle them but by looking at EBNF you could see it is possible to have multiple nodes underneath of an AND or OR. I am so confused right now. if a query has several nested AND and inside them, there would be many comparisons such as `GT | LT | EQ | IS` how should I iterate through it from top to bottom and perform all the logics and comparisons correctly?

sorry for such a long question. This is [my class project page](https://github.com/ubccpsc/310/blob/2017jan/project/Deliverable1.md)